# How to run a Java Selenuim test on a certain Chrome profielr

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I hope that you're fine. I'm new at Java Selenium automation, what I want to do is I want to run a test on a certain website but not in a clean session of ChromeDriver I would like to use a certain profile of mine I name it "test" its shortcut in the Desktop is "test.lnk", here what I did:

````
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
//import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AutomationTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/test");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
//      driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/click-counter.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @Test 
    public void testRegister() throws InterruptedException {
        do {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("addbtn")).click();
        } while(true);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
//      driver.close();
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")

chrom_options.add_argument("profile-directory=test)
```

specify only the user data folder in userdata dir argument

Pass profile directory separately